# segment fault cause by optimizer

Tags: java, curl, gdb, xml-rpc

We encountered one problem when trace log with gdb
.System crash when XMLRPC call and gdb backtrace show:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  finishCurlMulti (envP=0x0, curlMultiP=0xe37b800, timeoutType=timeout_no, 
    deadline=..., interruptP=0x0) at xmlrpc_curl_transport.c:572

warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
572
(gdb) bt
#0  finishCurlMulti (envP=0x0, curlMultiP=0xe37b800, timeoutType=timeout_no, 
    deadline=..., interruptP=0x0) at xmlrpc_curl_transport.c:572
#1  0x00002b84f0b4ad24 in performCurlTransaction (envP=0x46a185d0, 
    clientTransportP=0xe365d50, serverP=<value optimized out>, 
    callXmlP=<value optimized out>, responseXmlPP=0x46a185e8)
    at xmlrpc_curl_transport.c:1036
#2  performRpc (envP=0x46a185d0, clientTransportP=0xe365d50, 
    serverP=<value optimized out>, callXmlP=<value optimized out>, 
    responseXmlPP=0x46a185e8) at xmlrpc_curl_transport.c:1141
#3  call (envP=0x46a185d0, clientTransportP=0xe365d50, 
    serverP=<value optimized out>, callXmlP=<value optimized out>, 
    responseXmlPP=0x46a185e8) at xmlrpc_curl_transport.c:1362
```

===> Is  there null pointer error? envP=0x0

-------------------------------------trace frame 1--------------------

```
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x00002b84f0b4ad24 in performCurlTransaction (envP=0x46a185d0, clientTransportP=0xe365d50, serverP=<value optimized out>, callXmlP=<value optimized out>, 
    responseXmlPP=0x46a185e8) at xmlrpc_curl_transport.c:1036
1036               synchronous RPC can be in progress is for the 'perform' method
(gdb) print envP
$1 = <value optimized out>
(gdb) info registers
rax            0x0      0
rbx            0xec59270        247829104
rcx            0x0      0
rdx            0x2      2
rsi            0x46a18200       1184989696
rdi            0xe37b800        238532608
rbp            0x46a185d0       0x46a185d0
rsp            0x46a184e0       0x46a184e0
r8             0x46a17f00       1184988928
r9             0x46a17ef0       1184988912
r10            0x46a18100       1184989440
r11            0x206    518
r12            0xe365d50        238443856
r13            0xe37b800        238532608
r14            0xe99dda0        244964768
r15            0x46a185e8       1184990696
rip            0x2b84f0b4ad24   0x2b84f0b4ad24 <call+340>
eflags         0x10206  [ PF IF RF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0xe02b   57387
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x63     99
gs             0x0      0
fctrl          0x37f    895
fstat          0x0      0
ftag           0xffff   65535
fiseg          0x0      0
fioff          0x0      0
foseg          0x0      0
fooff          0x0      0
fop            0x0      0
mxcsr          0x1fa0   [ PE IM DM ZM OM UM PM ]
```

========> do envP store in register rbp?

------------------------Back to frame 0-------------------

```
(gdb) frame 0
#0  finishCurlMulti (envP=0x0, curlMultiP=0xe37b800, timeoutType=timeout_no, deadline=..., interruptP=0x0) at xmlrpc_curl_transport.c:572
572
(gdb) print envP
$2 = (xmlrpc_env * const) 0x0
(gdb) info register
rax            0x0      0
rbx            0x0      0
rcx            0x0      0
rdx            0x2      2
rsi            0x46a18200       1184989696
rdi            0xe37b800        238532608
rbp            0xe37b800        0xe37b800
rsp            0x46a182f0       0x46a182f0
r8             0x46a17f00       1184988928
r9             0x46a17ef0       1184988912
r10            0x46a18100       1184989440
r11            0x206    518
r12            0x0      0
r13            0x0      0
r14            0x0      0
r15            0x0      0
rip            0x2b84f0b49e93   0x2b84f0b49e93 <finishCurlMulti+259>
eflags         0x10206  [ PF IF RF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0xe02b   57387
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x63     99
gs             0x0      0
fctrl          0x37f    895
fstat          0x0      0
ftag           0xffff   65535
fiseg          0x0      0
fioff          0x0      0
foseg          0x0      0
fooff          0x0      0
fop            0x0      0
mxcsr          0x1fa0   [ PE IM DM ZM OM UM PM ]
```

========> Please tell me what is wrong in this case?

I'm  trying to use -O0 to disable optimizer but i don't sure.

Thanks.

Here is my backtrace with correct souce file:

```
#0  finishCurlMulti (envP=0x0, curlMultiP=0x12e2580, timeoutType=timeout_yes, deadline=..., interruptP=0x0) at xmlrpc_curl_transport.c:572
#1  0x00002abe7f51d0b4 in finishAsynch (clientTransportP=0x12e24c0, timeoutType=timeout_yes, timeout=10000) at xmlrpc_curl_transport.c:1301
#2  0x00002abe7f72f5c6 in xmlrpc_c::clientXmlTransport_http::finishAsync (this=0x12e2470, timeout=...) at client.cpp:624
#3  0x00002abe7f72f64a in xmlrpc_c::client_xml::finishAsync (this=0x1304bf0, timeout=...) at client.cpp:893
#4  0x00002aaaab57c26d in UrlStruct::runXmlRpc (this=0x122d140, method="mediacontrol.onEvent", paramList=<value optimized out>, result=<value optimized out>) at Utils.cpp:146
#5  0x00002aaaab57c526 in IVRUtils::executeXmlRpc (controllerUrl=0x12e2580, methodName=Traceback (most recent call last):   
#6  0x00002aaaab54366a in IvrCoreSession::_exec_xmlrpc_cmd (this=0x2aaab48277f0, paramList=..., result=0x41228cb0) at IvrCoreSession.cpp:307
#7  0x00002aaaab544c95 in IvrCoreSession::fireEndCallEvent (this=0x2aaab48277f0) at IvrCoreSession.cpp:504
#8  0x00002aaaab54752d in IvrCoreSession::~IvrCoreSession (this=0x2aaab48277f0, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at IvrCoreSession.cpp:101
#9  0x000000000047c15d in AmSessionContainer::clean_sessions (this=0x10cbdd0) at AmSessionContainer.cpp:94
#10 0x000000000047c898 in AmSessionContainer::run (this=0x10cbdd0) at AmSessionContainer.cpp:132
#11 0x000000000049266c in AmThread::_start (_t=<value optimized out>) at AmThread.cpp:70
#12 0x000000397ec0673d in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#13 0x000000397e0d40cd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

This bug occur every 6 days. And we use xmlrpc-c lib with curl build option **--enable-threaded-resolver**. Please give us some idea.
Thanks.

Comment: You most likely have a "feature" in your C code which causes a crash when used a particular way. I find it suspect that `envP=0x46a185d0` becomes `envP=0x0` in the method which fails.

Comment: I would also make sure the build is current so you don't get `warning: Source file is more recent than executable.`

Answer (score 1):

This looks dangerous:

> warning: Source file is more recent than executable

This means the debug symbols don't match your source code. Build and try again; you might be hunting a bug that has already been fixed.

Also check the code in `performCurlTransaction()` at `xmlrpc_curl_transport.c:1036` because this function gets `envP != null` but it calls `finishCurlMulti` with `null`.